# Spline graph date on x axis

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I've got an Api call that returns data in this format...

```
"values" : [ {
    "key_as_string" : "2011-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1317427200000,
    "doc_count" : 3
}, {
    "key_as_string" : "2011-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1320105600000,
    "doc_count" : 10
}, {
    "key_as_string" : "2011-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1322697600000,
    "doc_count" : 3
}, {
    "key_as_string" : "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1325376000000,
    "doc_count" : 3
}, {
    "key_as_string" : "2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1328054400000,
    "doc_count" : 9
}, ... ]
```

and I want to plot it with highcharts to make it look like [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time).

I'm mapping the data across to the format highcharts expects...

```
var graphData = $.map(rawData, function (item, i) {
    return  [[new Date(item.key),
             item.doc_count]]; //Note nested array as map will flatten 1 layer
});
```

By examining graphData in the debugger, the Dates are present and correct.

Finally, I'm setting up the graph like this:

```
$(Selector).highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total Emails'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%b %y',
            year: '%y'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Count'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Emails',
        data: graphData
    }]
});
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I can't get highcharts to display reasonable x-axis labels. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get a short date format showing on the x-axis? Since the data is monthly, I'd prefer the format `Jan 2011`.

As an aside, I have no idea why I'm not getting best-fit lines either so if it's simple, please let me know.

Comment: "By examining graphData in the debugger, the Dates are present and correct." -- Could you give a short example of how your graphData looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the `item.key` as it is without running it through javascript `Date`

```
var graphData = $.map(someApiData.values, function (item, i) {
    return [[item.key,
    item.doc_count]]; //Note nested array as map will flatten 1 layer
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Gk5m8/